# About the existence of a regular solution in a chaotic system

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, dynamical-systems

> Show that for some choice of $x_1\in\mathbb{R}$, the sequence given
>   by: $$ x_{n+1} = n-3^{x_n} $$ satisfies: $$ \lim_{n\to +\infty} x_n= +\infty. $$

I was able to prove the statement by showing that the odd-looking
$$ x_n = \log_3\big(n-\log_3\big(n+1-\log_3\big(n+2-\ldots$$
is well defined. Are you aware of other effective techniques?

I am especially interested in topological ones.

Comment: Is there a reason for the base $3$? Would it work also for base e or base $2$?

Comment: @JohnBentin: no particular reason, it should work in other bases, too.